# Regex search in XSL, select string after match

Tags: regex, xslt, saxon

I have a solution where the filename has a prefix showing the filesize of a PDF. I need to pick up that value in to a XML-file that has a lot of other info that is collected with the XSLT.

How ever I can't get just this Regex match to work.
Filename have this structure as this example:
776524_P9466_Novilon_Broschyr_SE_Omslag.xml where the digits before the underscore is the filesize.

I have a Regex search pattern of _(.*) and I can validate that it will match everything after the first section of the digits.

Here is my XSL that I'm having problems with:

```
<xsl:param name="find_size">
    <xsl:text>(_.*)</xsl:text>
</xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="filename_of_start"><xsl:value-of select="replace($filename_of_file, '$find_size', '')"/></xsl:variable>
    <artwork_size><xsl:value-of select="$filename_of_start"/></artwork_size>
```

$filename_of_file has the string: *776524_P9466_Novilon_Broschyr_SE_Omslag.xml*

I have also tried to match the digits before the underscore and replace with that match but haven't got that to work either. Other replaces where I remove other matches from the beginning of the string works.

Thanks

Comment: did you try `^(.+?)_` or `^([^_]+)_`?

Answer (score 2):

How about using the substring-before() XPath function?

```
<xsl:variable name="file_size" select="substring-before($filename, '_')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `replace($filename_of_file, '$find_size', '')` you want `replace($filename_of_file, $find_size, '')`.